# Error instantiating mechanize object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I have no idea what the problem is on this. I'm trying this in the rails console:

```
>> agent = Mechanize.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

I added gem 'mechanize' and did a bundle install. I did require 'mechanize'. I also tried require 'nokogiri' below that, and every time I get the same error. I've tried 4 or 5 different ways to instantiate a new mechanize object and haven't been able to find one.

I searched my entire rails app for the string '.user' and couldn't find any. Not sure what the deal is here. Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT

Full Stack trace

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.2/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:866:in `proxy='
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:1189:in `set_proxy'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize.rb:204:in `initialize'
from (irb):5:in `new'
from (irb):5
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/Dropbox/Work/RubymineProjects/apps/my_app/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /home/me/Dropbox/Work/RubymineProjects/apps/my_app/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you add the entire stack trace?

Comment: It looks like something to do with your http proxy.

Comment: I'm not using a proxy as far as i know. I'm on my home network, no proxies. I'm using a VM though, would that make a difference? How can I solve this, because I don't understand how even if I was behind a proxy, the object instantiation throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong: the version of mechanize that came out a few days ago is buggy. I solved that error just updating the gem (i.e., with `bundle update mechanize`).

Comment: Right you are! this is the first time I've tried to use it, so I didn't even think that it could have been a bug. Thanks again!